# How do I sort my I books by how recently they were added?

Tags: books

In Books on iOS if I sort by "recent" I see a jumble of my recently read books interspaced with books labeled as "new", which includes books that I've had for years.

PDFs, in particular, seem to jump the queue, so that they tend to displace books that are actually "recent" in the way the word is use in non-Apple English.

What does "recent" mean in Apple Books? And how do I configure Books so that sorting by "recent" sorts by recent?

Comment: You can't configure (same on macOS). I am pretty sure "recent" is not just one of recent purchased, recently added, recently opened, recently completed, recently updated, or recently something else. Maybe it is some combination of time related characteristics. But the results is "jumble".

Comment: @Gilby Also it seems, PDFs (some) also randomly get pushed to the top for no reason (and sometimes marked "new" as well. Basically then, I'd take "it means nothing" for an answer.